# how to upload video in chunks to google drive using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I have a google chrome extension that records the current tab and on the stop of the recording, it uploads the video to google drive successfully in a specific folder.

I'm looking for how to upload the video while the recording is still in progress? Meaning the blobs which I am getting from recording gets uploaded to the. google drive.

```
var superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {
    type: 'video/mp4',
});

var metadata = {
    name: Date.now() + '.mp4',
    mimeType: 'video/mp4',
    parents: [folderId],
};

var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }));
form.append('file', superBuffer);

var xhrDriveRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrDriveRequest.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id');
xhrDriveRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhrDriveRequest.responseType = 'json';
xhrDriveRequest.send(form);
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar for webcam recording using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC). The library provides a `timeSlice` integer in milliseconds and a `ondataavailable( blob )` callback that will be called after every `timeSlice` period. You can then simply post the received blob to the server and stitch the blobs back together into a single file.

For example in PHP you would simply append or write the blob-data into file:

```php
$filePath = '/path-to-file'; // path for each recording process created from an id or something unique
if (isset($_FILES["blob"])) {
    // If the path already exists we are receiving further blobs => append, else write new file
    $fp = fopen($filePath, file_exists($filePath) ? "a" : "w");
    fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($_FILES["blob"]["tmp_name"]));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: for that, I need to get the id of my file - how I will get the id on the very first chunk upload?

Comment: here I am using google drive API to upload.

Comment: If you do not have any sessions or something to identify the process with you could for example create an ID from the current timestamp `Date.now()` and send that ID with every post request to the server

Comment: I don't know about google drive api, you will have to look up the docs on how to incrementally build a file. However - regarding your initial question - recordRTC does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API can perform a [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable). It will allow you to keep uploading while your screen is being recorded.

As a summary of how resumable uploads works:

- Create a `POST` request with the `uploadType=resumable` parameter and get the resumable session URI inside the Location header. Remember that as you don't know the length of the file, the `X-Upload-Content-Length` should not be setted.
- Keep creating `PUT` requests to that URI with the `Content-Length` set to the number of bytes in the file.
- If something was wrong, resume the upload. Remember that you can set the `Content-Range` to `*/*` if you don't know the total file size, and the space of the new chunk.

Comment: I implemented the same logic for the first event.data it throws 308 which is good but for the next one it gives me 503 with no response also, Content-Range to */* again didn’t work as it is looking for the range.

Comment: Have you followed points 5 and 6 indicated in [Resume an interrupted upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resume-upload)?

Comment: Yeah, I did, also as stated here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132489107 - parallel uploading is not featured by the API. If you have any working example would be great thanks.

Comment: I have followed the resumable uploads instructions listed and it has worked as expected. It all depends on how the recording process has been implemented. Could you share more information on how it works?